# Adding an array of dates to modifiers in react-day-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I need to have three kind of days in my calendar. Disabled, active and non-active. (Disabled and non-active are not the same in this case). 
I can send in an array of dates to 'disabledDays', no problem.

I can't seem to work out how to send an array of dates into the modifiers props. I've read this [info](http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/matching-days) many times and there it does not say anything about that it is possible to send in an array of dates to the modifiers, can that be? I have an array of dates ready, I just want to send that in as a modifier and name it for example 'activeDays'. Tried multiple things but the modifier style never gets added to the date in the calendar.

Thanks in advance